# Listview with disable rating bar

Tags: android, listview, ratingbar

I have a rating bar for every item on the list view when the user rate the item i disable the rating bar using ***`ratingBar.setEnabled(false);`***
the problem that when user clicks on it again after disabled it does setOnItemClickListener function , instead I want to make toast or to do nothing.

Comment: show your code for better help

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one from these options, once user clicks the rating bar for the first time :

```
    ratingBar.setClickable(false);
```

or

```
    ratingBar.setOnItemClickListener(null);
```

Comment: I want to do setOnItemClickListener function but not when click on rating bar (on click on any thing else in the row) with these two options it disable all  setOnItemClickListener.